# Reading Chinese characters from URL content / JSON - Google Places

Tags: php, utf-8, chinese-locale

I give up. After 2 days of researching I would like to ask the experts.
I am trying to read the Google Place information via PHP and am doing this:

```
    $link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJIwa7XTyIGGARGn0k_6aUb8I&language=ja&key=APIKEY";
echo getContent($link);

function getContent($link){

            if(!$fp = fopen($link ,"r" )) { 
                echo "false";
            }else{
                $tmp = ""; 

                while(!feof($fp)) {
                    $tmp .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
                }
                fclose($fp);
            }
        return $tmp;
        }
```

And while this works great for all US and European based places, I struggle with Chinese and Russian Characters (e.g name or address).

**Expected** Output: BumB 東京スポーツ文化館 (eg name: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJIwa7XTyIGGARGn0k_6aUb8I&language=ja&key=APIKEY via Browser)

**Received** Output: BumB æ±äº¬ã‚¹ãƒãƒ¼ãƒ„æ–‡åŒ–é¤¨ (via PHP)

I do understand that this is some kind of encoding error - but not sure how to handle it. Tried all kinds of encodings to UTF8, but no success so far.

Thanks for any support that will help me find a solution!
fj

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Looks like I found the solution. That was easier than expected!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be so easy.

PHP did not set the default to uft8 and this did the trick:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Hope that this will help someone painful searching one day!